# No catch checkbox value in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is the code ....

```
String Columnas[] = {"Rol","Asignado"};
modeloTabla= new DefaultTableModel(null,Columnas);          
objSAP = new SAPFunctionCall();
try {
    rolese = objSAP.listaRoles();
    modeloTabla.setNumRows(rolese.size());

    for (int i=0; i<rolese.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<1; j++){
            modeloTabla.setValueAt(((BeanRol)rolese.get(i)).getStrNomRol(), i, j);
            modeloTabla.setValueAt(Boolean.FALSE, i, j+1);
        }
    }       
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();                    
}       

tblRol = new JTable();      
tblRol.setModel(modeloTabla);

tblRol.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new CheckBoxCellEditor());
tblRol.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new CWCheckBoxRenderer());
```

Now when I want to capture the value of the checkbox ...
For example row 0 column 1...

```
Object obj;
Boolean bol;
obj = modeloTabla.getValueAt(0, 1);

if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
    bol = (Boolean) obj;

if (bol == true)
    System.out.print("SELECTED");
else
    System.out.print("NO SELECTED");

}
```

Now as Annex I attached these 2 classes....

```
public class CheckBoxCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected JCheckBox checkBox;       

    public CheckBoxCellEditor() {
        checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        checkBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        checkBox.setBackground(Color.white);            
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
        JTable table,Object value,boolean isSelected,int row,int column) {
        checkBox.setSelected(((Boolean) value).booleanValue());
        return checkBox;
    }         

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return Boolean.valueOf(checkBox.isSelected());
    }
}

public class CWCheckBoxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CWCheckBoxRenderer() {
        super();
        setOpaque(true);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Object value,boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus,int row,int column) {
        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            setSelected(((Boolean)value).booleanValue()); 
            setEnabled(table.isCellEditable(row, column));

            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
                setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            }
            else {
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
                setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    return this;
    }
}
```

Repeat does not capture!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please 1) Remove every 2nd (blank) line from the source. 2) Figure how to use code formatting. 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 4) Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

- please read tutorial about [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- `Boolean` value representing [JCheckBox as Renderer and Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) too
- then there no reason for creating `TableCellRenderer` and `TableCellEditor` for `JCheckBox` in `JTable`
- if you want to hightlighting `TableCell` depends of `Boolean` value that returns `JCheckBox`, then read [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)
- examples in the tutorial and [here too](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Table-Renderer-Editor.htm)

Comment: @Miguel What was your final solution?